# Challenges starting off with Gradle, Spring and DB2

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle, build.gradle

My idea of the project is to write a simple Spring pure java application using Gradle that will connect to a DB2 database and pull some data and print on the console.

To start off, I created a Gradle project using Eclipse Luna.

My challenges:

1. How do I read the database.properties file in src/main/resources which has the db.driver, db.url, db.username and db.password ?
2. How do I tell Gradle to pick up my db2cc4.jar for the driver ? I cannot manage it with Gradle dependencies because it is a proprietary jar.

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

jar {
    baseName = 'QueryExecutor'
    version =  '0.1.0'
 }

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.0.RELEASE'
    runtime files('lib/db2cc4.jar') 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
  }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.1'
}
```

Here is my ApplicationConfig.java

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import org.shrinathk.queryexecutor.persistence.QueryExecutorDAO;

@Configuration
@Import({DatabaseConfig.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig
{
    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public QueryExecutorDAO queryExecutor()
    {
    return new org.shrinathk.queryexecutor.persistence.QueryExecutorDAO();
    }
}
```

Here is my DatabaseConfig.java

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig
{

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER   = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL      = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
    }
}
```

The database.properties file

```
db.driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
db.url=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE
db.username=db2admin
db.password=db2admin
```

Here is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The structure of the project (e.g. `src/main/resources`) is the same as it was in maven. When You prepare the artifact to deploy it should be automatically moved to appropriate location.
2. When it comes to adding `db2jcc.ar` dependency what You need is a [flatDir](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#flatDirMulti) or adding the following piece of code under `dependencies` section:

   `compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: Thank You! The `compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')` worked.

Comment: One more question - The properties files are packaged inside the final jar. How do I keep them separate ? The whole idea of properties file is to ensure that there is no dependency on the jar and that any change in properties should not need a jar build. Whenever the jar executes, it will pick up the properties from the specified location (in our case, the same dir the jar is in).

Comment: When it comes to excluding properties into `jar` or `war` You need to google for 'gradle exclude properties'. It can be done in `jar` or `war` task or probably also in `processResources` configuration. I don't remember it by heart :/

Comment: `processResources` altogether removes the properties file which causes my JUnits to fail (as they require DB connections to connect and query). `jar { exclude '*.properties' }` does the trick. It uses the properties in the project for JUnits, but excludes them from the jar.

Comment: That means that You need to configure it in `war` or `jar` using exclude.

Comment: Yes. The properties need to be excluded in the `war` or `jar` and I mentioned in the earlier comment.

Comment: Ah sure, didn't notice that. Glad You worked it out :)